# Change toggle button state from service

Tags: android, service, state, togglebutton

Is it possible to change `ToggleButton` state (checked/unchecked) from service?

I am passing boolean value via `SharedPreference` after togglebutton click(checked) and reset it after stop recording at service (service is still running after it). 
But how i can change `ToggleButton state`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen sharedprefs changes via [OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html). So from service set boolean flag in prefs. Listen for your flag from activity and change toggle button state.

- You also can use LocalBroadcastManager to send message when you stop
  recording.
- Activity can give a callback to a service which it should
  call when recording it stopped.
- You can use [EvenBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to
  communicate between app components.

There are a lot different ways.

Comment: thx!! OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener would do the job, cause activity isnt always running with service.